# Autocomplete working on first row but not work on new line

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I want to autocomplete on each row but it is working only on first row.

autocomplere working fine on first row but when i add new line there autocomplete does not work.
My code is here
any solution please

Here is HTML:

```
<table id="items">
    <thead>
        <th>Items</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><input class="input3 item" name="name_1" type="text" value="" autocomplete="off"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
    <br clear="both">
    <div id="addmore">Add new line</div>
```

Here is Jquery:

```
// add new line
$("#addmore").click(
  function () {
      var someText = '<td><input class="input3 item" name="name_2" type="text" value=""></td>';
     var newDiv = $("<tr>").append(someText);
     $('#items').append(newDiv);
  }
);

// get autocomplete tags
    var availableTags = [
      "ActionScript",
      "AppleScript",
      "Asp",
      "BASIC",
      "C",
      "C++",
      "Clojure",
      "COBOL",
      "ColdFusion",
      "Erlang",
      "Fortran",
      "Groovy",
      "Haskell",
      "Java",
      "JavaScript",
      "Lisp",
      "Perl",
      "PHP",
      "Python",
      "Ruby",
      "Scala",
      "Scheme"
    ];

    $( ".item" ).autocomplete({
      source: availableTags,
      minLength: 1,
    });
```

You can see in Js Fiddle: `http://jsfiddle.net/anosim/n3auc/4/`
Please help me, Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your new row is dynamically added so I think your add a new line function needs some additional code like this:

```
            $("#addmore").click(
              function () {
              var someText = '<td><input class="input3 item" name="name_2" type="text" value="">   </td>';
              var newDiv = $("<tr>").append(someText);
              $('#items').append(newDiv);
              $( ".item" ).autocomplete({
              source: availableTags,
              minLength: 1,
              });
             }
            );
```

JSfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/n3auc/7/

Comment: Thank you @gloria answer is helpful for me.

Comment: please help me in this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30637709/how-to-add-new-line-in-text-area-in-jquery-mulitple-autocomplete-when-pressing-e